# Create fast-export package from Mercurial repository

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, plasticscm

I'm trying to find the way to fast-export a hg repository and dump the result into a fast-export compatible format file.

Basically I want to do the same that I can do with Git or Plastic SCM:

```
git fast-export --all -C --tag-of-filtered-object=drop --signed-tags=strip > Repository.fast-exported


cm fast-export MyProject@PlasticSCMServer:8087 Repository.fast-exported
```

I know I can do the fast-export/fast-import directly into Git using the hg-fast-export.py tool (http://hedonismbot.wordpress.com/2008/10/16/hg-fast-export-convert-mercurial-repositories-to-git-repositories/) but I'm wondering if I can create the dump file.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [this project](http://repo.or.cz/w/fast-export.git)?  The `fast-export.sh` script works by piping the output of the `hg-fast-export.py` python script into `git fast-import`.  If you wanted to save the dump file, you could simply run the same command and direct the output to a file.

Comment: Yes, that tool actually works but it's using an old file format called "inline" and I'm trying to move a Hg repository to Plastic SCM and the Plastic SCM seems that is not able to manage the "inline" format.